# iR Remote TO IR Reciever in phone TO PC

Tags: remote, kodi, infrared, irda

I'm too cheap and stingy to buy a proper USB infrared receiver for my PC, however my phone (Nokia N95) has a receiver built in. I know for a fact that there must be some API to access it (for Tx at least) as the *[irRemote](http://irremote.psiloc.com/)* works.

Is there any good programs available or how would I start to set up so that my phone sends all the iR data captured by it over Wifi or Bluetooth to my Windows PC for use in XBMC or other programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have shown is a program on the phone itself that can access the raw infra-red diode and send custom signals.

So, yes there is most likely an API that allows you to build programs on a phone that does similar activities, however, I have not seen any program that allows you to use infra-red and Bluetooth features from a phone on a pc simply by attaching a cable.

You may be able to write a program that sits on your phone and can receive or do file activities, then have a separate program on your pc that can interface to this program and transfer any copied files from the phone to the pc - but I highly doubt it would be possible to actually make the IR/Bluetooth interface visible to the pc... Unless you are good at soldering!

Comment: Yes, the software side is what I was more or less asking about. On my PC i'd be happy to convert the signals with custom software, it's more I was looking if there was anything like this that already existed for symbian because I don't think the API is public (and software I mentioned isn't open source) and writing any code for symbian is shockingly hard.

Answer (score 0):

What you need, is an IrDA device.
If you got some skills with electronic parts (PCBs / Connectors etc), You can DIY.

Here some nice guide for it:
[Building an Infrared Transmitter for Your PC](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/86).

If you can't deal with it, there is the "expensive" option:
[USB To Irda Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006LSINO).

Comment: Be careful here. Remote control devices are usually consumer IR, not IrDA. There's no guarantee that IrDA receiver will work with remote.